# Ruby/GSL online documentation for wrong version?

Tags: ruby, version, gsl

After successfuly installing Ruby/GSL library on my Debian (via *deb), with Ruby 1.9.3, I am having troubles running most of the GSL methods. Specifically, [this webpage](http://ruby-gsl.sourceforge.net/samples.html) shows several code samples, but ([in Arrays](http://ruby-gsl.sourceforge.net/array.html)), right from the top line, `require "GSL"` is obsolete, it is `require "gsl"` today. The remaining methods also do not work.

For another example of my problem, [consider another online reference to Ruby/GSL](http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/rb-gsl-win/rb-gsl-1.7.0/html/math.html).

```
GSL::VERSION
#=> 1.15
GSL::pow_2( 4 )
#=> 16
```

But when [I flip the page](http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/rb-gsl-win/rb-gsl-1.7.0/html/complex.html),

```
GSL::Complex.new( 0.9, 1.1 )
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(2 for 0)
```

The simplest explanation to me would be that Ruby/GSL has more than one version hanging online, and the documentation I found is for the old one. For example, there is this abandoned version (https://github.com/codahale/ruby-gsl), so perhaps the version history is a bit complicated? Which is the authoritative version, and where can I finde the up-to-date documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following methods do work for the Complex module:

```
> c = GSL::Complex[0.9, 1.1]
=> GSL::Complex
[ 9.000e-01 1.100e+00 ]

> c.real
=> 0.9
> c.imag
=> 1.1

> c.pow 2
=> GSL::Complex
[ -4.000e-01 1.980e+00 ]
```

Comment: Great. So all that obsolete documentation was misleading me. Do you know where can I find the up-to-date documentation?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky It seems you have to build upto-date docs with rdoc or yard from ruby-gsl sources by yourself. There is documentation from 2010 at http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/files/rdoc/ref_rdoc.html and at least it does contain updated info for Complex class. If my answer did helped you, feel free to mark is as accepted.

Comment: It did help, thanks. I was looking everywhere online and I completely forgot about good old rdoc :-)